# assign value and display values are not same in javascript

Tags: javascript

Have some doubts about the javascript. when I try to console

```
a = 021
console.log(a) // 17
```

why it is changing and how to store the exact value in the variable

Comment: Check for `console.log(window.a);`

Comment: because 021 is not a number (can't start from 0), so use it as string then: `a = '021';`

Comment: Since the number is started with `0`, it'll be considered as an Octal value. Hence it's returning 17.

Answer (score 3):

Because with leading zero it's a octal-number so 21 is 2*8+1 = 16.
But when you print it out it's in decimal.